# Finding equally separated string/words in alphabetical order in Go

Tags: algorithm, go, alphabetical

I'm trying to find words/strings that are equally separated within a circular arrangement of the alphabet. for example:

- “zzzzyyyybbbzzzaaaaaxxx” is a list consisting of “xyzab” with separation 0 {xy, yz, za, ab}
- “aco” is a list with separation 11 {co, oa}

Hence, I wanted to write function IsSeparated(B) and returning true if B is "isSeparated"

Below are my codes/solution:

- first, i tried to remove the duplicates in the string to make it easier for to count the separation
- second, i sort the string in alphabetical order
- third, after sorting, i count the separation for each letter
- in the "isSeparated" method I tried to make it count in circular arrangement by using `maxpair -1 == count` since there'll always be 1 letter that has no pair for example
- `[{ab} {bx} {xy} {yz} {za}] - [{0} {21} {0} {0} {0}]]//there are 5
  pairs = maxPair -1({-xy}`

hence, the since it's in circular arrangement, the middle one will always be the odd one, which is 21, which are not equally separated with the rest of the pairs

This is the part where it gets tricky and I can't seem to get the desired output. what could possibly be the right way to find the length/separation of each letters in alphabetical order and check if they are uniformly separated.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

//Q3
func separationCount(x, y string) int {
    alphabets := [26]string{"a","b","c","d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u","v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    separation := 0

    for i:=0; i < len(alphabets); i++{
        if x == alphabets[i]{

            for j:= i+1; j <len(alphabets); j++{
            if y == alphabets[i+1]{
            fmt.Println(separation)
            return separation
            }else{
                i++
                separation++
            } 
            }
                }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    //fmt.Println(separation)
    return 0
}

func isSeparated(B [] string) bool {
    var N int = len(B) - 1
    var maxPair int
    var item1 string
    var item2 string
    var separation int = 0 
    count := 0
    var intialSeparation int

    //calling the methods
    fmt.Println("Original array:",B)
    B = removeDuplicates(B)
    B = sortedList(B)

    item1 = B[0]
    item2 = B[1]
    intialSeparation = separationCount(item1,item2)

    for i := 0; i< N; i++{
        item1 = B[i]
        item2 = B[i + 1]

        separation = separationCount(item1,item2)
        maxPair++
        if intialSeparation == separation{
            count++
        }

        if maxPair == count{
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }

    }
    return false
}

//to sort the alphabets 
func sortedList(B []string) [] string {
    N  := len(B)
    //max := 0
    element1 := 0 
    element2 := 1

    for element2 < N {
        var item1 string = B[element1]
        var item2 string = B[element2]

        //using function call
        if greater(item1, item2){
            B[element1] = item2
            B[element2] = item1
        }
        element1++
        element2++
    } 
    fmt.Println("Alphabetically sorted:", B )
    return B
}

//for sorting
func greater(a, b string) bool {
    if strings.ToLower(a) > strings.ToLower(b) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  //removing duplicates
func removeDuplicates(B []string) []string {
    encountered := map[string]bool{}

    // Create a map of all unique elements.
    for v:= range B {
        encountered[B[v]] = true
    }

    // Place all keys from the map into a slice.
    result := []string{}
    for key, _ := range encountered {
        result = append(result, key)
    }
    fmt.Println("Duplicates removed:", result )
    return result
}

func main(){
    //q3
    B := []string{"y", "a", "a", "a", "c", "e", "g", "w", "w", "w"}
    fmt.Println(isSeparated(B))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite follow the part where you try to determine the separation. In Go, like in C, you can do arithmetic on characters. For example, you'll get the 0-based index of each lower-case letter with:

```
pos := char - 'a';
```

You can the turn `"abxyz"` to

```
{0, 1, 23, 24, 25}.
```

If you take the difference between adjacent letters, you'll get

```
{-25, 1, 22, 1, 1}
```

(-25 ist the difference between the last and the first value.) You have two gaps: One where your cycle begins between b and w and another one where the alphabet wraps. The second gap is where the difference is negative, always between the last and first items. You can add 26 to the difference to adjust it or you can use modular arithmetic, where you use the remainder `%` to account for the wrapping:

```
diff := ((p - q + 26) % 26;
```

The `%` forces the result to the range from 0 to 25 if the first operand is positive. The + 26 enforces that it is positive. (The program below uses 25, because your definition of separation is not the difference in position, but the number of lterres in between.)

Now you have the differences

```
{1, 1, 22, 1, 1}
```

When you have only at most two dfferent values and one of them occurs at most once, your condition is met. (That's a condition which I find surprisingly complicated to test, see below, but part of that is because Go's map is a bit cumbersome.)

Anyway, here's the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func list(str string) int {
    present := [26]bool{}
    pos := []int{}

    count := map[int]int{}

    // determine which letters exist
    for _, c := range str {
        if 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' {
            present[c-'a'] = true
        }
    }

    // concatenate all used letters (count sort, kinda)
    for i := 0; i < 26; i++ {
        if present[i] {
            pos = append(pos, i)
        }
    }

    // find differences
    q := pos[len(pos)-1]
    for _, p := range pos {
        diff := (p - q + 25) % 26

        count[diff]++
        q = p
    }

    // check whether input is a "rambai"
    if len(count) > 2 {
        return -1
    }

    which := []int{}
    occur := []int{}
    for k, v := range count {
        which = append(which, k)
        occur = append(occur, v)
    }

    if len(which) < 2 {
        return which[0]
    }

    if occur[0] != 1 && occur[1] != 1 {
        return -1
    }

    if occur[0] == 1 {
        return which[1]
    }

    return which[0]
}

func testme(str string) {
    fmt.Printf("\"%s\": %d\n", str, list(str))
}

func main() {
    testme("zzzzyyyybbbzzzaaaaaxxx")
    testme("yacegw")
    testme("keebeebheeh")
    testme("aco")
    testme("naan")
    testme("mississippi")
    testme("rosemary")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ERhLxC_zfjl

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as what the question wanted. I really appreciate this. However, what if I want to get sorted rambai using method "sortedrambai(str, k)"  and returns all the rambai in 1) ascending order of the number of distinct letter. 2) ascending order of the length 3) alphabetically. for example i want rambai of 0, hence that would be : sortedrambai(str, 0) returns [aa, bb, bb, dd, .... poop, tutu, deeded, abc, rust....] and such

Comment: Hi @anon_n52: That's a simple matter of storing the results in an array or maybe slice of struct and then sort these results. Frankly, this all looks like some homework. It's clear that you still have problems with some basic concepts. That's no shame, but you should try to learn about how arrays and structs work. It takes time to get experience and it won't help if I provide a ready-made solution here. (The problem might be that most Go dcos and tutorials I find seem to be addresses ad people who already know how to program in another language such as C or C++.)

Comment: I totally get it. Honestly yes I am still struggling understanding Go cause we've been using java this whole time. But thank you so much for your time and effort. I really understand your explanation. Thank you again and sorry for any inconvenient caused!